# LinkedIn Open Graph multiple images sharing

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I used Open Graph protocol for sharing pages via LinkedIn. I've added multiple tags og:image, but when I try to share, in share dialog I have first image from meta tags and 2 another from page content. 
Can somebody tell, how to manage multiple images sharing using OG.

Code example:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="websiteUrl" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Test Title" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://tamgdeya.ru/photos/norm/1/1_jS37XHMl.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/n/nature_illusion_studio-44987-1300868181.jpeg" />
```

Share dialog: http://prntscr.com/bcxwi9